# Media Files are not loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl-certificate, combres

I have provided the ssl certificate for the website where it is hosted. after doing this changes the https content are not loading. i have restarted iis also but no use.
Currently in system we are loading all the CSS and JS file using combres.xml
But non of the media files loading. Currently using framework 4.0

can any one help me out.

Comment: What are the errors in your web browser and/or your server logfile ?

Comment: error in the web browser is like Loading failed for the <script> with source. if i try with the http i can able to see the scripts that are loading media files